# Spring Boot Multiple Database (AWS Elasticbeanstalk)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Spring Boot App deployed in AWS ElasticbeansTalk and two AWS RDS database shema. On my local machine both databases are working. However, after deploying in elasticbeanstalk enviroment only "crosscheckdbxr" is working, stated as Primary. From second database "sectiondbxr" I could not retrieve data. Could you check below configuration and advice.

Application.properties configuration,

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.db1.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://devdbxr.cnk8oyka2f9o.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/crosscheckdbxr
spring.db1.datasource.username=admin
spring.db1.datasource.password=
spring.db1.datasource.member.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.db2.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://devdbxr.cnk8oyka2f9o.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/sectiondbxr
spring.db2.datasource.username=admin
spring.db2.datasource.password=
spring.db2.datasource.member.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Database configuration for "crosscheckdbxr",

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "userentityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef= "usertransactionManager", basePackages = {"com.xr.crosscheck.repository.user"})
public class UserConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "datasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.db1.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "userentityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("datasource") DataSource dataSource){
        HashMap<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "update");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
                .properties(properties)
                .packages("com.xr.crosscheck.model")
                .persistenceUnit("db1")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "usertransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("userentityManagerFactory")EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

Database configuration for "sectiondbxr",

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "sectionEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef= "sectionTransactionManager", basePackages = {"com.xr.crosscheck.repository.section"})
public class SteelSectionConfig {


    @Bean(name = "sectionDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.db2.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "sectionEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean SectionEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("sectionDataSource") DataSource dataSource){
        HashMap<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "validate");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
                .properties(properties)
                .packages("com.xr.crosscheck.model")
                .persistenceUnit("db2")
                .build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "sectionTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager SteelTransactionManager(@Qualifier("sectionEntityManagerFactory")EntityManagerFactory SectionEntityManagerFactory){
        return new JpaTransactionManager(SectionEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Sample Repository,

```
@Repository
public interface CSectionsRepository extends JpaRepository<CSections, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT SECTION from sectiondbxr.C", nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> getAllColumn();

    @Query(value = "SELECT * from sectiondbxr.C u where u.section = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    CSections findBySection(String sectionN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by making database column headers capital letters. There was problem with reading database. After changing column titles with capital letters data retrieving worked.